# Can i use a bare metal switch as a PHY layer switch?

Tags: switch, switching, layer1

Is it possible to use a bare metal switch circuit switching its ports to emulate a reconfigurable PHY level switching between input ports?
Is doing so needs advanced operating systems or just using Open Network linux is sufficient?
Is there a less wasteful way for doing this with another hardware of comparable price and performance(48*10G+4*40G)?

EDIT:
as stated in comments I need the ability of dynamically change the connections between in ports and out ports. actually i want to send bundles of output ports to some transponders and then some MUXes and then send this WDM outputs to different directions. The role of switch is not adding regeneration as TPXs do 3R regenration. its role is adding reconfigurablity. here is a demonstration of what i am thinking of:

[image]

Comment: I cannot find that the manufacturer offers optional, paid support for this product. Also, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: I named the device as an example of bare metal switches, and in last question the request is not for an specific device or model i asked for another device type... @RonMaupin

Comment: You are not going to be successful trying to use a layer-2 switch as a layer-1 switch. You can get a layer-1 switch, and it will perform as a layer-1 switch. Layer-2 switching is primarily done in hardware, so you really can't bypass that.

Comment: can't i port mirroring or VLAN or...  for this? It seems that layer2 switches do a much more complicated task and in case of bare metal switches for lower prices... @RonMaupin

Comment: "_can't i port mirroring or VLAN or... for this?_" Now, you are asking about layer-2 frame delivery, not layer-1 switching. If you want to switch at layer-1, it is completely different than layer-2 switching. Layer-1 switching involves electrically connecting two ports, but layer-2 switches don't do that. In fact they electrically isolate ports.

Comment: So...This can't provide 'similar' functionality? i.e. sending one ports I/O to another and inverse, with more latency and ...?

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do. You can send frames from one interface to another interface, that is what layer-2 switches do, but a layer-2 switch will terminate the ethernet link from the host. A layer-1 switch will extend the layer-1 link to a different interface, so it appears to just be part of the cable.

Comment: @mhk Are you looking for a layer 1 switch? If so, product suggestions are off-top here but if you just "Google" for "layer 1 switch" they will show up. They are hand for a remote lab for example so that you don't have to go to site to re-patch equipment to change the lab topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the ability of dynamically change the connections between in
>   ports and out ports.

That is what a layer-1 switch does. You cannot convert a layer-2 switch into a layer-1 switch. A layer-1 switch lets you physically connect different ports through configuration. A layer-2 switch simply doesn't have that hardware. Yes, there is a large price difference, but you will need to get the correct equipment for the requirements.

There are several manufacturers that make layer-1 switches. Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. You could try asking for one that meets your specific needs on our sister site, [Hardware Recommendations SE](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

A "PHY layer switch" isn't possible. For a start, what's the framing of the traffic?

Perhaps you are thinking of a SFP-based regenerator. For example, this [ghip CONV 2004](https://ghipsystems.com/cms/en/network-units/modular-conv/). They can be thought of as connecting the two SFP's GMII interfaces back-to-back. As such they have no understanding of the framing (although the CONV2004 is an advanced unit, and so has a electrical tap of the GMII which examines the symbols on the interconnection to do error reporting, and for that reporting it needs to know what the symbols mean, and thus if the traffic is ethernet/SONET/SDH/TV/etc).

Or perhaps you are thinking of the similar devices available for interception applications, with an SFP's GMII interfaced to another SFP's GMII, and a tap of that GMII bus running to two additional SFPs to transmitting copies of the east-west and west-east received traffic. Although even these devices are increasingly using ethernet switching, to allow typical ethernet features on the links to the interception host, such as autonegotiation. Other than for 1000Base-T, these devices aren't very popular as a optical 50:50 splitter is more economic, assuming sufficient optical budget is available. Even for 1000Base-T the wide availability of 4 port switches with a "port copy"/"span"/"intercept" feature gives strong competition to a GMII-based device.

Comment: There are several companies that make layer-1 switches: http://thenetworksherpa.com/what-is-a-physical-layer-switch/

Comment: The framing is ethernet(SONET/SDH is a bonus but not needed currently for our application). I need the ability of dynamically change the connections between in ports and out ports. actually i want to send bundles of output ports to some transponders and then some MUXes and then send this WDM outputs to different directions. The role of switch is not adding regeneration as TPXs do 3R regenration. its role is adding reconfigurablity.

Comment: by in and out ports i mean client and line or downlink and uplink... actually i want to divide switch ports to two groups of 24 ports...

Comment: and further the problem with physical layer switches is their price compared to this bare metal ones... a bare metal with mentioned specs is roughly 5K but for a PLS the price tag stands on roughly 20K...

Comment: There's also "SDN" WDM Muxes on the market, maybe these would be more useful for your application?